# Pyautogui-module is not installing with pip3 on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, pyautogui

I'm developing with python 3 and trying to install the pyautogui Module, and to be able to use it I had to install some packages. But I keep getting errors when installing the packages with pip3.

```
Collecting pyobjc-framework-Quartz
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a9/af/fb7a7264d3bf0147bdd1d01eeb4e8b1cac90f0613aca336b178771dcdec7/pyobjc-framework-Quartz-6.2.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-4ukazwoa/pyobjc-framework-Quartz/setup.py", line 67, in <module>
    py_limited_api=True,
  File "/tmp/pip-install-4ukazwoa/pyobjc-framework-Quartz/pyobjc_setup.py", line 390, in Extension
    os_level = get_os_level()
  File "/tmp/pip-install-4ukazwoa/pyobjc-framework-Quartz/pyobjc_setup.py", line 200, in get_os_level
    with open("/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist", "rb") as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist'
----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-4ukazwoa  /pyobjc-framework-Quartz/
```

Anyone has a idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Anything related to Objective C, `pyobjc` and especially `pyobjc-framework-Quartz` require Mac OS X. You cannot install them at Ubuntu.